# Problem regarding Row and Column Space, when does two matrices have same Row or Column Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Below I've summarised my understanding of the topic till now. Please correct me wherever I am wrong.

Row operations preserve the row space of a matrix but do not preserve the column space in general (the only preserve the dimension of column space)

Column operations preserve the column space but not the rowspace in general(only preserve dimension of rowspace)

Two matrices $A$ and $B$ have

(a) The same column space iff it is possible to column reduce $A$ to $B$ OR iff it is possible to row reduce transpose($A$) to transpose($B$) [Since column space of A is same as rowspace of its transpose]

(b) They have the same row space iff it is possible to row reduce $A$ to $B$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. If you want to dig a bit further, the reason is that when reduce $A $ to $B$ (by rows, for example) in each step you replace a row by a linear combination of the current ones, in such a way that the subspace spanned by the rows does not change.